# I want to add a "div" field on clicking the add button. How do i do it?

Tags: html, angular5, angular6, angular7

I have used this solution for adding fields:- [Add DOM element on Button click with Angular 2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666254/add-dom-element-on-button-click-with-angular-2)

But I am not able to achieve the desired reuslt.

Html:-

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let fields of addFields">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <label>Choose Category</label>
      <select (change)="getVal($event)">
        <option value="0">--</option>
        <option *ngFor="let service of services" value="{{service._id._id}}">{{service._id.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <label>Choose Service</label>
      <select (change)="getServiceVal($event)">
        <option value="0">--</option>
        <option *ngFor="let ser of servicess" value="{{ser.name}}">{{ser.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Add Service" (click)="add()">
```

TS:-

```
 addFields = ['fields1']
  fieldsNumber = 1;


  add(){
    this.fieldsNumber++;
    this.addFields.push("field"+this.fieldsNumber);
   }
```

Comment: this should work. are there any errors you're getting?

Comment: yes.. when I press on add button another div appears but when i select category once again then the upper div contents disappear. Its like we are adding same div again again.. but it doesnt have any unique id so the selected data disappears.